# How to sort table php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sorting

How to make php codeigniter codes to make feature to 'sort table' by user needs.

I have set the query in models on my final web project (https://github.com/HermesED/KharismaArt)

**Models: Project_Model**

**Controller: admin(dir)/pengurus**

**View: Admins(dir)/pengurus_admin.php**

Sorry for directing you guys to github, because Idk how to post codes here.

It works on sorting table field 'NIM' or ('Student_Id') in English. But that's "automatic" from coding. I want to make manual feature, like in sorting table things just like MS Excel

But I really don't have idea to create feature for sorting table in views.

Can anyone help? Or do you have some useful website for references?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just briefly look your code. Before suggesting you the answers I want to know the numbers of rows the tables can have. Tell me the approximate count. Is it more than 100 or less than 100.

Comment: @GeordyJames I have 42 field rows so far on tbl_members. And it will increase later.

Answer (score 1):

Try editable jquery it's provide sorting, pagination and search feature.

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

i hope it's works

Answer (score 0):

As the number of rows of each table is less than 100 the easiest way to implement sortable table is by using a free javascript plugin named [Dynatable](https://www.dynatable.com/).The simple way to implement Dynatable your project is given below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dynatable/0.3.1/jquery.dynatable.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dynatable/0.3.1/jquery.dynatable.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dynatable();
  });
</script>
   <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
             <tr>
              <th><b>NIM</b></th>
              <th><b>Nama Lengkap</b></th>
              <th><b>Program Studi</b></th>
              <th><b>Angkatan</b></th>
              <th><b>Status</b></th>
              <th><b>Delete</b></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <?php 
              foreach($anggota as $pengurus){
            ?>

            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $pengurus->nim;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $pengurus->namalengkap;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $pengurus->programstudi;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $pengurus->angkatan;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $pengurus->status;?></td>
              <td>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('admins/pengurus/hapus/'.$pengurus->nim)?>">
                  <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
             <?php }?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

If the number of rows increases more than 100 then [Data Tables](https://datatables.net/) is recommended. But its implementation needs to break your codes and it is a little complicated and not recommended for tables with small sizes.

Remember you need to import jquery before using it and for every table assign different table ids. Clicking on any table header field will sort the table according to that field.